# Showing custom static block on the custom page Magento

Tags: magento, content-management-system, block, frontend, routes

I have a some question about Magento cms static block showing on the custom page.
For example, I have 3 static block (block 1, block 2, block 3) and I need to display block 1 at the Category 1 and subcategories 1, block 2 at the Category 2 and subcategories 2, and block 3 at other pages (home, about, etc)

I try to use `Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getRequest()->getRequestUri()`

But I received request like "category1.html" and if we going to subcategory of this category - block is changed to default.

If use `Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getRequest()` I received "catalog/category/view/id/id_number"

I really don't understand how to solve this issue.

Thanks for answer!

Comment: Your question is a bit confusing.  Are you trying to assign a static blocks to specific categories?

Comment: Yes, I have only 3 category + subcategories and other pages like homepage, shipping etc, and I want to show 3 different static blocks created in admin on this categories (cat1+subcat1 = block1 etc) and block 4 for other pages..

Comment: Why can't you use the built in functionality that allows you to assign static blocks to categories?  I've added an answer that outlines the steps to do this.

Comment: thanks for answer, but this block need to show in the footer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a block to a specific part of the page, for a specific category using the **Custom Layout Update** functionality.

**NOTE: If you have a custom theme, the reference name for the footer could be different.  This method has been tested to work on the Modern theme included with Magento**

1. Go to **Catalog > Manage Categories**
2. Choose the category you want to assign your block to.
3. Go to the **Custom Design** tab.
4. Set **Use Parent Category Settings** to `No`
5. In the **Custom Layout Update**, insert the following XML
   `<reference name="bottom.container">

   <block type="cms/block" name="my_footer_block">
       <action method="setBlockId"> 
           <block_id>my_footer_block</block_id>

       </action>

   </block>

   </reference>`
6. Replace `my_footer_block` with the **Identifier** (block_id) of your static block.
7. Clear your Magento Caches under **System > Cache Management** and refresh the Category page.

If this does not work, the reference name may not be correct for the theme you are using.  You can check the reference name by looking under `app/design/frontend/[THEME PARENT]/[THEME CHILD]/layout/page.xml` and searching for `page/html_footer` within the file.

In the file, you will find something like this:

```
<block type="page/html_footer" name="footer" as="footer" template="page/html/footer.phtml">
    <block type="page/html_wrapper" name="bottom.container" as="bottomContainer" translate="label">
        <label>Page Footer</label>
        <action method="setElementClass"><value>bottom-container</value></action>
    </block>
    <block type="page/template_links" name="footer_links" as="footer_links" template="page/template/links.phtml"/>
        <block type="page/switch" name="store_switcher" as="store_switcher" template="page/switch/stores.phtml"/>
    </block>
    <block type="core/text_list" name="before_body_end" as="before_body_end" translate="label">
        <label>Page Bottom</label>
    </block>
</block>
```

Note the `name` attribute for the `page/html_wrapper` block.  This is the name references used in the code provided in step **Step 5**.  If it's different than `bottom.container`, change `bottom.container` to match what is in your **page.xml** file.

Answer (score 1):

this might help you

```
Strategy : Check current page is whether current category is available on current page or not, If available then you can check it's level and depending on that you can show you block

Solution :
$_current_category=$this->getCurrentCategory();
1)get current category and if category not available then show default block
2)if category found get it's level $_current_category->getLevel() and then you can place your block accordingly
```

Answer (score 0):

Override catalog.xml in you local module
Add in 

in content reference

in you catalog/category/voew.phtml
add this code

$_current_category=$this->getCurrentCategory();

if(cond == '1st category') {
 echo $this->getChildHtml('block1');
}

Similarly for other blocks

Answer (score 0):

You can simply assign a static block to specific categories using the built in functionality Magento provides.

1. Go to **Catalog > Manage Categories**
2. Click the category you want to assign the block to on the left.
3. Go to the **Display Settings** tab
4. Set **Display Mode** to either `Static block only` or `Static block with products`.
5. Set **CMS Block** to the static block you want to display on this category.
6. Click the **Save Category** button.

Repeat this step for different categories.  You can choose a unique static block, or assign the same one to multiple categories this way.

Comment: I tried this version, but I need to show current block in footer

Comment: I've added another answer detailing how to do this.  In the future, please specify all details of what you are trying to achieve, down to placement on the page (in your case, a static block in the footer of a category).  This will allow people here to give you a correct answer for what you are trying to achieve.